# Jquery, cant get .attr() to work on my element to make a function fire when it is loaded?

Tags: javascript

script:

```js
$(".cad .et_pb_row .field__items").attr('onload=','startMoving(this)');
```

html:

```html
<div class="et_pb_row homepage-news-boxes course-finder-subjects">
           <div class="field__items">
```

Im attempting to add an attribute but I can't get it to add to the element.

Comment: divs don't have an onload attribute afaik

Comment: Ive attempted to add it onto the image items within that div but also to no avail

Comment: don't put `=` in first argument for `attr` function

Comment: just an off topic suggestion... there are much better ways to add an event listener than using that approach. something like `element.addEventListener` ... or if you are stuck with jQuery `$(element).on('eventname', function)`

Comment: you just need to put in your DOM Ready function a call to the function passing the reference to the correct element (div, image or whatsoever). It's hard to tell you more without seeing the function and the relevant DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it this way

```
$(".cad .et_pb_row .field__items").attr('onload','startMoving(this)');
```

Comment: Thankyou, dont know how I missed that extra = in there, this was indeed the issue, thanks :D